# react-datepicker and react-hook-forms: required not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

React-datepicker and react-hook-form. I am trying to make react-datepicker required, but its not working

```
<Controller
    name="resetDateTime"
    control={control}
    required
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Datetime
            onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
            selected={field.value}
            inputProps={{
                placeholder: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm",
            }}
            viewMode="time"
        />
    )}
/>
{errors.resetDateTime && <span>This field is required</span>}
```

When I submit form without selecting any datetime, I am expecting the error to be show, but instead it submits the form

Comment: You need to provide a runnable code in https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Controller />` has no `required` prop, instead of you have to pass the validation rules via the `rules` prop. Check the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for more info.

```
<Controller
    name="resetDateTime"
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Datetime
            onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
            selected={field.value}
            inputProps={{
                placeholder: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm",
            }}
            viewMode="time"
        />
    )}
/>
{errors.resetDateTime && <span>This field is required</span>}
```